# Convert a list of tuples into a table with columns which have checkmarks based on one element of tuple

Tags: microsoft-excel, transform

This is one of those things that would be easy to find tutorials on *if I only knew what this kind of operation was called!*

I've got a CSV that looks like this

```
Fruit,color
Apple,red
Apple,green
Apple,yellow
Banana,yellow
Pear,brown
Pear,green
```

I want a CSV that looks like this (rendered as a markdown table for convenience of the reader):

| Fruit | brown | green | yellow | red |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | N | Y | Y | Y |
| Banana | N | N | Y | N |
| Pear | Y | Y | N | N |

IOW, in this test case, the 2nd column of the CSV is an enumeration, and I want the values in that column to be "spread" across columns of the result becoming "column masks".

Order of the enum columns in the output table doesn't matter.   Field values in the output table doesn't matter (can be Y/N or Y/blank or anything that distinguishes present from absent.  Headers don't need to be present (as long as I can figure out which column is which in the output table).

I'm thinking Excel but I'm open to other commonly available tools. I suppose I could write an Awk script but I'm sure there's some kind of UI way to do this in a few clicks in Excel, ...

*if only I knew what it was called!!!* (It's gotta be some kind of grouping/summary operation ...)

Comment: I actually _did_ solve this with awk.  But there's gotta be a way to do it in Excel, so I'm leaving this question up ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1. Use **Text to Columns** (Data tab > Data tools group) to split the data into 2 columns.

Step 2. Please copy them to other cells, and use **Remove Duplicates** (Data tab > Data tools group) for each column.

Select one column > click Remove Duplicates > Continue with the current selection > Remove Ruplicates to get the unique value.

Step 3. Please copy the color column, go to Home tab > Clipboard group > expand Paste option > **Transpose(T)**.

At this step, you can get the row and column names of the table.

[image]

Step 4. Take the sample of image as a example, enter the formula below in cell G2, then fill right, down.

`=IF(SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$7=$F2)*($B$2:$B$7=G$1))=1,"Y","N")`

[image]

Comment: Excellent!  Learned a couple of things here! First: you can transpose on paste, didn't know that.  Second: very clever use of [inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product)! (Though why they call it `SUMPRODUCT` is beyond me, how is a person supposed to recognize it if they go around renaming it?)  Thanks!